# what is the command to display .eps files?

Tags: osx, postscript

I'm have a file called `t-0.8.eps`.

How can I open this file in the shell?

I am using Mac and when I click `.eps` files the preview (the name of the software to read PDFs) says failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, you can use `open` from the terminal to open any file with its default application (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264395/linux-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command)). `open` is Mac OS-specific. On GNU/Linux, the equivalent is usually `xdg-open`.

Also, for your reference, you can try to find out what type of file a file really is (regardless of its extension) using the `file` command.

Comment: I typed to terminal                               ...$ file  t-0.8.eps                                        and it says
t-0.8.eps: empty

Comment: @Meva This means just what it says: this is an empty file. It seems it was created incorrectly.

Comment: Won't `open` do exactly the same thing as double clicking the file (which is what the OP did)?

Comment: @terdon It will. That's exactly the point. The way I read the question, the OP is looking for a way to open files from a terminal the same way they are opened with a double-click. In any case, the actual issue seems to be that the `.eps` file is incorrectly created (see [the OP's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/57664/meva))

Comment: @JosephR. yeah, I know, I reached the same conclusion in the comments to my answer. But the OP states that they already tried clicking and `preview` failed, so `open` will make no difference.

Comment: @terdon ...which is why I prefaced my answer with "in general": I meant it to be informative for the general problem of "How to open any file from the CLI?".

Answer (score 12):

Files with the `.eps` extension are usually [encapsulated postscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript). You can view them with `gv`:

```
gv t-0.8.eps
```

Or with your favorite PDF viewer:

```
evince t-0.8.eps
```

Or even with an image editor

```
gimp t-0.8.eps
```

Comment: Gimp says :  Opening '/....../Documents/Gerris Programs/Tutorials/rayleigh-taylor/t-0.8.eps' failed: Unknown file type          And I have no evince or gv?

Comment: @Meva what operating system are you using? If Linux, which distribution? If Debian/Ubuntu/Mint etc, just run `sudo apt-get install gv` or `sudo apt-get install evince`. Anyway, you should have a pdf viewer installed, try `okular`. If none of these work, please update your question with the output of `file t-0.8.eps`.

Comment: mac 10.9.1 I am using.I have preview to read pdf files but when I click eps files preview says failed..

Comment: @Meva please **always** include your OS in your questions. Also, show me the output of `file t-0.8.eps` as I requested. Apart from that, you could try [macghostview](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5815/macghostview) available for OSX

Comment: it says empty  when I type file t-0.8.eps

Comment: @Meva there you go then, that's the problem. The file is empty which is why it can't be read.

Comment: So something must be wrong in the software. Maybe uninstalled packages . Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape can open and edit eps files.  It won't fix an empty file though.